# Do tcp sockets have a built in checksum?

Tags: vb.net, sockets

Do tcp sockets have a built in method for calculating data corruption?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the TCP protocol has a checksum. That checksum is small and using a weak algorithm, though. You cannot trust it with your life. It might be enough for youm or not. There are papers about it failing.

Note that sockets are a distinct concept from the TCP protocol. I assume you meant TCP, not sockets.